# .exe file made by pyinstaller pops up DLL error. tkinter is crashing

Tags: python, json, tkinter, exe, python-3.10

I have made simple application with `tkinter` and `json` libraries. The complexity is quiet big because there are few classes in separated .py files which are "tree-like connected". **The script itself works perfectly** but once I use `pyinstaller` to make it into .exe file this error occurs.

Execute error:

[image: Execute error]

Line 8 Erro:

[image: Line 8 Error]

I am using 2 pictures, one as background and second one as a frame picture, 1 label and 1 textbox. Even when I manually add images folder into dist folder it does not help.

Build command is as follows:

`venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe Editor.py --distpath ./Ready_For_Testing --workpath ./temp_build --specpath ./spec_build -w --hidden-import tkinter`

Comment: Can you provide the lines mentioned in the error (importing lines) and also information either it's working when you run the python script or not?

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu I have just add Line 8 error in my code into the problem description. However, as I have said, script itself works (without building it) but once built, this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have just solved this issue even so it is **manual solving**.

> If you use virtual enviroment you should go in your enviroment for example mine: D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv

> If you use system/allFor Python go inside your Python, path could look like this : C:\Users\YourLogin\Programs\PythonX.X

> > Inside in the Python folder copy folder named **Library** and just paste it inside your folder with .exe file. File you built with pyinstaller.

Feel free to remove any other folders inside **Library** but **bin**, that must stay. It's key to solve the issue.

If you have images which are used in `tkinter` you have to copy and paste them inside your build folder as well.

It's simple and easily done. Hope this will help some others who will face the same issue.

**EDIT:** I found out that there is a way to solve this by adding more options inside your `pyinstaller` command.

**Command:**

```
pyinstaller.exe Editor.py --distpath ./Ready_For_Testing --workpath ./temp_build --specpath ./spec_build --paths D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv\Library\bin --hidden-import tkinter --hidden-import tkinter.filedialog --collect-all tkinter --windowed --hidden-import tkinter.messagebox
```

Main thing in the command is that you **have to detect missing libraries/dlls** which you can find inside stdout while "installing" .exe file.

Here is exact **Warning** output which you should look for in case of similar or same problem:

```
674 WARNING: lib not found: liblzma.dll dependency of D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
690 WARNING: lib not found: LIBBZ2.dll dependency of D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
721 WARNING: lib not found: ffi.dll dependency of D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
737 WARNING: lib not found: tk86t.dll dependency of D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
737 WARNING: lib not found: tcl86t.dll dependency of D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
```

When you take a look inside Library\bin folder inside enviroment there you can see these missing files. And that is **why** you have to add them in `--paths` option.

[Missing dlls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HieoF.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just so you know I cannot add pictures as visible since I do not have 10+ reputation.